# Websocket server for Python3 outside HTTP server

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, websocket

I am searching for a websocket server implementation for **Python3**.
There are some projects on the web, but they all run in HTTP-context.
I need a server that is started on command line, not by an HTTP-server (No HTTP-Handler object available)

Ideally, the code should not require any bigger third party-project (like twisted, tornado ...)

Any ideas?

Concrete description of my use case: *My network contains several python servers (not web servers). Every of these Python servers logs runtime information to a logger. Now, I want be able to listen to those logs from within a browser... and websocket seems the most interesting solution to me...*

Comment: Why no HTTP handler available? All versions of python ship with BaseHTTPServer built-in. Are you removing it for some reason?

Comment: You got me wrong, what I was saying is that I do not have an **instance** of this class. I do simply have a normal socket that I would like to wrap in a websocket...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) project support python3. The websocket.py module that websockify is built on implements a generic python WebSocket server. It currently requires the numpy module if you want to use the new versions (HyBi-07+) of the protocol (I will probably implement a slower generic fallback in the next couple of days).

You also might be able to use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) with [pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/) to get it running in python 3. pywebsocket is really the reference implementation of WebSockets that both Chrome and Mozilla test against.

Comment: I already spent some time on websockify and its dependency to numpy was one of the reasons I dropped it. I gave the migration of pywebsockets a try (which seems indeed to be the project I am looking for) but I didn't succeed to migrate it to Python 3. I have now temporarily implemented Hybi myself (thanks inspirations taken from pywebsockets code). I will try to continue migration of pywebsockets soon when I have some time to spare...

Comment: @gecco FYI, I pushed out the change already to websockify to use the array module instead of numpy when numpy is not available. Also, if you feel this sufficiently answered your question, don't forget to select the answer (for those who follow and for your own SO answer rate).

Comment: Since I still do not have a sufficient answer to my question I'd prefer to leave it open...

Comment: @gecco. I have removed the numpy reference from my answer since as I noted, it is no longer required. Can you clarify what you feel is not yet answered about your original question? Websockify support python 3 and does not require any external modules. Also, the answer may sufficiently answer your actual question and be useful to others (that is part of the reason for selecting it) even if you yourself decide to go a different route.

Comment: The answer IS useful but it seems to me that it does not exactly answer my question. websockify objects only fit for HTTP-servers. I do have a TCP-server.

Comment: The WebSocketServer class in websockify is a real WebSocket server, not an HTTP server. It includes a few lines of code to answer simple HTTP requests, but that is an optional feature included for convenience. The minimal web serving functionality is only activated when the `web` parameter is passed to the initializer (i.e. `--web ROOT` on the websockify command line).

Comment: Ok, I had a closer look to your code tonight and it seems indeed to be close of what I'm searching for... thanks for insisting :-)